# In a JTable when selectin a value of the row it shows me the previous value

Tags: java, swing, jdbc, jtable

I'm doing an university project and I've encountered in a error.

I've obtained 3 values from my DB (name, address, type) and I want to show them in a JTable and it works, but when I make another query searching for another value it shows it to me in the table but, when I press on a row, the table shows me the previous value.

Ex.

First query: name = centerName1, address = fake street - fake city, type = hospital
|name | address | type |
|:---: | :------: |:----: |
|centerName1| fake street - fake city | hospital|

Second query: name = centerName2, address = fake street 2 - fake city 2, type = hospital
|name | address | type |
|:---: | :------: |:----: |
|centerName2| fake street2 - fake city2 | hospital|

After the second query the table shows me in the columns "Nome Centro", "Indirizzo", "Tipo Centro" values "centerName2", "fake street 2 - fake city 2", "hospital" but, when I press the row the value changes to "centerName1", "fake street - fake city", "hospital".

Anyone know what could be the problem?

Thanks for help.

**homepage.java class:**

```
...
        search.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                
                String researchText = find.getText();
                
                List<InfoCentriVaccinali> centriVaccinali = new ArrayList<>();
                if(researchText != null && researchText.trim().length() > 1)
                    try {
                        centriVaccinali = stub.cercaCentroVaccinale(researchText);
                    } catch (Exception ex) {
                        ex.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    
                
                String[] columnNames = {"Nome centro", "Indirizzo", "Tipo Centro"};
                DefaultTableModel tableModel = new DefaultTableModel(columnNames, 0);
                
                table = new JTable(tableModel) {
                    public boolean editCellAt(int row, int column, java.util.EventObject e) {
                        return false;
                     }
                };
                table.setRowSelectionAllowed(false);
                
                for(int i=0; i<centriVaccinali.size(); i++) {
                    String nome = centriVaccinali.get(i).getNomeCentro();
                    String indirizzo = centriVaccinali.get(i).getIndirizzo();
                    String tipo = centriVaccinali.get(i).getTipoCentro();
                    
                    Object[] infoData = {nome, indirizzo, tipo};
                    
                    tableModel.addRow(infoData);
                }
                
                
                scrollPane = new JScrollPane(table);
                scrollPane.setBounds(1, 150, 798, 150);
                panel_Homepage.add(scrollPane);
            }
        });
```

**InfoCentriVaccinali.java class:**

```
public class InfoCentriVaccinali implements Serializable {
    
    private String nomeCentro;
    private String indirizzo;
    private String tipoCentro;
    
    public InfoCentriVaccinali(String nomeCentro, String indirizzo, String tipoCentro) {
        this.nomeCentro = nomeCentro;
        this.indirizzo = indirizzo;
        this.tipoCentro = tipoCentro;
    }
    
    public String getNomeCentro() {
        return nomeCentro;
    }
    
    public String getIndirizzo() {
        return indirizzo;
    }
    
    public String getTipoCentro() {
        return tipoCentro;
    }
}
```

Comment: Some code like the 3 System.out.println are used only as """debugging""" funcion

Comment: 1) For better help sooner, [edit] to add a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/). Hard code data for the `JTable` or source it from data known to the JRE (e.g. fonts or locales). 2) Java GUIs have to work on different OS', screen size, screen resolution etc.  using different PLAFs in different locales.  As such, they are not conducive to pixel perfect layout.  Instead use layout managers, or [combinations of them](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5630271/418556) along with layout padding and borders for [white space](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17874718/418556).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not removing the previous table from the GUI. You just add the new one. And since there is no `LayoutManager` (you set it to `null`), then every time you set add the table to the panel, all those tables end up in the same spot. You are also creating a new table with a new table model for every search instead of using a single table with a single model.

So what you can do is:

1. Use a proper `LayoutManager`.
2. Add all `Component`s once at the constructor (including one table).
3. Set the model of the table to be a `DefaultTableModel`.
4. For each search, update the `DefaultTableModel` you created for the single table, instead of creating a new model and a new table every time.

Follows the code partially corrected to update the table properly (assuming you uncomment the related RMI call which returns the list of results), but it does not use a `LayoutManager` yet:

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel;


public class HomepageGUI extends JFrame {
    
    private static final int WIDTH          = 800;
    private static final int HEIGHT         = 600;
    private static final String FIND        = "Ricerca per Nome, Comune, Provincia o Vaccino";
    
    boolean resetText = true;
    
    JPanel panel_Homepage;
    JFrame frame_Homepage;
    JLabel log_Citizen;
    JLabel log_Doctor;
    ImageIcon searchPicture;
    JButton search;
    JTextField find;
    JTable table;
    DefaultTableModel tableModel;
    JScrollPane scrollPane;
    
    public HomepageGUI() {
        panel_Homepage = new JPanel();
        frame_Homepage = new JFrame();
        
        frame_Homepage.setTitle("CENTRI VACCINALI");
        frame_Homepage.setSize(WIDTH, HEIGHT);
        frame_Homepage.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame_Homepage.setResizable(false);
        frame_Homepage.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame_Homepage.add(panel_Homepage);
        
        panel_Homepage.setLayout(null);
        
        /**
         * Label cittadino
         */
        log_Citizen = new JLabel("Login as a citizen");
        log_Citizen.setBounds(650, 20, 100, 25);
        panel_Homepage.add(log_Citizen);
        
        /**
         * Label dottore
         */
        log_Doctor = new JLabel("Login as a doctor");
        log_Doctor.setBounds(650, 40, 100, 25);
        panel_Homepage.add(log_Doctor);
        
        /**
         * Bottone ricerca
         */
        searchPicture = new ImageIcon("ext-img/Search.png");
        search = new JButton(searchPicture);
        search.setBounds(171, 100, 29, 29);
        
        tableModel = new DefaultTableModel(new String[]{"Nome centro", "Indirizzo", "Tipo Centro"}, 0) {
            @Override
            public boolean isCellEditable(int row, int column) {
                return false;
            }
        };
        table = new JTable(tableModel);
        
        search.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                
                String researchText = find.getText();
                
                List<InfoCentriVaccinali> centriVaccinali = new ArrayList<>();
                if(researchText != null && researchText.trim().length() > 1)
                    ; //Read from RMI server here... Code commented out because of no MRE in the question.
//                    try {
//                        centriVaccinali = stub.cercaCentroVaccinale(researchText);
//                    } catch (Exception ex) {
//                        ex.printStackTrace();
//                    }

                tableModel.setRowCount(0); //Removes all existing rows from the table model.
                
                for(int i=0; i<centriVaccinali.size(); i++) {
                    String nome = centriVaccinali.get(i).getNomeCentro();
                    String indirizzo = centriVaccinali.get(i).getIndirizzo();
                    String tipo = centriVaccinali.get(i).getTipoCentro();
                    
                    System.out.println(nome);
                    System.out.println(indirizzo);
                    System.out.println(tipo);
                    
                    Object[] infoData = {nome, indirizzo, tipo};
                    
                    tableModel.addRow(infoData); //Just adds to the model which updates the table.
                }
            }
        });
        table.setRowSelectionAllowed(false);
        scrollPane = new JScrollPane(table);
        scrollPane.setBounds(1, 150, 798, 150);
        panel_Homepage.add(scrollPane);
        panel_Homepage.add(search);
        
        /**
         * Campo ricerca
         */
        find = new JTextField(20);
        find.setText(FIND);
        find.setBounds(200, 100, 400, 29);
        panel_Homepage.add(find);
        
        frame_Homepage.setVisible(true);
        
        
        log_Citizen.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {

            @Override
            public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {
                //LoginCitizenGUI LogCitizen = new LoginCitizenGUI(stub);
                frame_Homepage.dispose();
            }

            @Override
            public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) {
                log_Citizen.setForeground(Color.RED);
            }

            @Override
            public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e) {
                log_Citizen.setForeground(Color.BLACK);
            }
        });
    
        log_Doctor.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {
                //LoginDoctorGUI LogDoctor = new LoginDoctorGUI(stub);
                frame_Homepage.dispose();
            }

            @Override
            public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) {
                log_Doctor.setForeground(Color.RED);
            }

            @Override
            public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e) {
                log_Doctor.setForeground(Color.BLACK);
            }
            
        });
        
        find.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                if(resetText) {
                    find.setText("");
                    resetText = false;
                }
            }
        });
    }
    
    public static void main(final String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(() -> {
            new HomepageGUI();
        });
    }
}
```

RMI and JDBC seem unrelated.

#### Other notes:

For your/our convinience there are also classes like `MouseAdapter` and `MouseInputAdapter` which you can use in order to not have to implement all methods of a `MouseListener`. Those classes implement `MouseListener` interface with empty body methods, so you can just override the ones needed.

Comment: [`DefaultTableModel`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/table/DefaultTableModel.html) can be updated like so: use `setRowCount(0);` on it to remove all rows, and then use `addRow` to add each new row. See my edit which includes some code.

Comment: THANKS! Now it works, I've passed 2 days trying to understand what could be the problem. Thanks a lot

Comment: No problem! Thank you for accepting this. Is there anything else you would like me to explain? You can read about `LayoutManager`s [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/index.html) (which is a complete tutorial on them) so that you can select a proper one.

Comment: In this case I've intentionally not used a LayoutManager so I can put all the stuff where I want, in other GUI's I've tried some LayoutManager like GridLayout or FlowLayout

EDIT:
I've looked your link and I found the GroupLayout, it seems the perfect one to use in my case, now I'm going to try to implement it